# Ui.Router using lazyLoad imports JS files, but buttons lose functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

The SmartAdmin template uses lazyScript to import the JS files, it works, everything works fine, but when I navigate between the pages the Ui buttons stop working. I can not understand because the files are incremented in the page, and whenever I use F5, they come back to work only in that page ...

```
angular.module('app.analytics', ['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

          $stateProvider
             .state('app.equipmentManagement', {
                url: '/gestao-de-equipamento',
                views: {
                    "content@app": {
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/equipmentManagementAnalytics.html'
                    }
                },
                data:{
                    title: 'Analytics'
                },
                resolve: {
                    scripts: function(lazyScript){
                        return lazyScript.register([
                            'build/vendor.graphs.js',
                            'build/vendor.ui.js'
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.eventFrame', {
                url: '/event-manager',
                views: {
                    "content@app": {
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/eventManager.html'
                    }
                },
                data:{
                    title: 'Event Manager'
                },
                resolve: {
                    scripts: function(lazyScript){
                        return lazyScript.register([
                            'build/vendor.graphs.js',
                            'build/vendor.ui.js'
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the template does not recognize the Widgets, because the "data-widget-grid" directive can not contain itself in another DIV.

I just resolved by removing the "data-widget-grid" directive from the children